# How to emulate class template argument deduction pre-C++17?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, rhel

I am working on removing `sscanf()` calls from a C++ codebase and replacing them with the `std::stringstream` implementation described here:  https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-C-alternative-to-sscanf .  The relevant code is:

```
template<class Char> 
class imatch 
{ 
    const Char* s; 
public: 
    imatch(const Char* x) :s(x) {} 
     
    template<class Stream> 
    friend Stream& operator >> (Stream& st, const imatch& m) 
    { 
        std::basic_string<Char> x; 
        st >> x; //strip spaces, read chars up to space 
        if(x!=m.s) st.setstate(st.failbit); //set as "failure" a mismatch 
        return st; 
    } 
};
```

Then in my codebase:

```
std::stringstream ss("value = 15"); //the input 
 
int val=0; 
ss >> imatch("value") >> imatch("=") >> val; 
 
if(ss) 
{ std::cout << "read value = " << val << std::endl; } 
else 
{ std::cout << "read failed" << std::endl; }
```

This uses class template argument deduction in the constructor calls.  It works great...in C++17.  The problem is that this code needs to compile all the way back to RHEL6, which only supports `-std=c++0x` at best (a subset of C++11).

What is the most succinct way to write and use this class such that users can easily port their `sscanf()` calls to use it, without access to C++17?

Comment: Do you really need the Char template parameter at call site? I would simply do a using c_imatch = imatch<char>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A common workaround was to provide a `make_xx` function that can rely on traditional template argument deduction:

```
template <typename T>
imatch<T> make_imatch(const T* t) { 
    return imatch<T>(t);
}
```

Comment: So how would you use this?  `ss >> make_imatch<char>("somestring") >> make_imatch<char>("someotherstring") >> val`?

Comment: @matoro I fixed a single character typo (or oversight); it now works with `make_imatch("somestring")` with no `<>` at all.

Comment: @matoro - there is no need to explicit the template type calling `make_imatch()`; the trick of a make_xx function is exactly to permit the template deduction, so `ss >> make_imatch("somestring") >> make_imatch("someotherstring") >> val`

Comment: Ah, that works great, thank you!  A little more verbose than I would have hoped but I'll just come up with a shorter name for it.